# Purpose of Comma in this sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas

> The only area where progress is lagging is the provision of high-efficiency irrigation systems to growers, mostly owing to technical factors such as the unavailability of clean water to prevent clogging.

What is the purpose of comma which is after "growers".

Comment: t is usual to set off such adjuncts with punctuation to avoid them being read as part of the preceding phrase. They would also be set off by intonation in speech.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave it out, then the reader may think the clause "mostly owing ..." applies to the growers.

Of course, that phrase applies to "progress is lagging", and explains *why* progress is lagging.